# How to get total number of ads, clicks and views by referrer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
 select AD_ID,to_char(adate,'YYYY-MM-DD') DT,upper(referrer) REFERRER, 'NOT 
 TRACKED' SOURCE, sum(views) VIEWS, sum(clicks) CLICKS
 from (
       select ad_id,adate,referrer,case f when 'Y' then hits else 0 end 
       clicks,case f when 'N' then hits else 0 end views
       from advert_view_hits
       where
       adate <= to_date('2019-10-15','YYYY-MM-DD') AND adate >= 
       to_date('2010-10-14','YYYY-MM-DD')
       and ad_id in
       (
         select ad_id from advertisements where acc_id=200830 and status in ('P','C')
       )
       )
 group by ad_id,adate,referrer
```

It produces and output like the following:

```
AD_ID,DT,REFERRER,SOURCE,VIEWS,CLICKS
1352824,2018-03-14,CORBIN & KING ,NOT TRACKED,2,1
1352824,2018-03-15,CORBIN & KING ,NOT TRACKED,6,0
1352824,2018-03-27,CORBIN & KING ,NOT TRACKED,11,1
1353137,2018-03-28,CORBIN & KING ,NOT TRACKED,1,0
1353137,2018-03-29,SEND TO FRIEND,NOT TRACKED,5,5
1353494,2018-04-19,COCKTAIL BARTENER,NOT TRACKED,1,0
```

But i want to produce an output like:

```
Referrer,          Adverts, Views,  Clicks
CORBIN & KING,     4,      20,     2
COCKTAIL BARTENER, 1,    1,      0
SEND TO FRIEND     1     5       5
```

Basically totaling up the number of ad's, view and clicks by referrer. I am unsure how to go about this with oracle.

Comment: How are the last three columns calculated?  And what happened to `'SEND TO FRIEND'`?

Comment: The last three columns are just the totals of all the rows per referrer.

Comment: I never included it as its just another referrer. The numbers in my examples are not accurate they are just an example of how the format should look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems so complicated.  You seem to want logic like this:

```
select referrer,
       sum(case f when 'Y' then hits else 0 end) as clicks,
       sum(case f when 'N' then hits else 0 end) as views
from advert_view_hits
where adate <= date '2019-10-15' and
      adate >= date '2010-10-14' and
      ad_id in (select ad_id
                from advertisements
                where acc_id = 200830 and status in ('P', 'C')
               )
group by referrer;
```

This doesn't match your exact results, because you haven't explained how to calculate them.  And the calculation is not obvious from the given data.

The `adverts` column seems to be:

```
count(distinct ad_id || trunc(adate))
```

Comment: The number of adverts are just meant to be based on the ad_id

Comment: This is certainly much closer t my goal thank you. You assumption about the last three columns was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, changing de group by clause. The inner select is the same:

```
select upper(referrer) REFERRER, 
       count(*) ADVERTS, 
       sum(views) VIEWS, 
       sum(clicks) CLICKS
from (
       select ad_id,adate,referrer,case f when 'Y' then hits else 0 end 
       clicks,case f when 'N' then hits else 0 end views
       from advert_view_hits
       where
       adate <= to_date('2019-10-15','YYYY-MM-DD') AND adate >= 
       to_date('2010-10-14','YYYY-MM-DD')
       and ad_id in
       (
         select ad_id from advertisements where acc_id=200830 and status in ('P','C')
       )
      )
 group by referrer
```

Comment: If I change adverts to count(distinct ad_id) as Adverts the data is correct but I think the first answer may be better. Thanks.